# C - Assigning value of argv to a variable

Tags: c, parsing, variables, argv, argc

I am parsing the name of my .txt file as a parameter into the command line when calling the program.
I want to assign the .txt file's name to a char variable.

[image]

Here is my attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < argc; i++)
        printf("argv[%d] = %s\n", i, argv[i]);

    FILE *fPointer;
    if ((fPointer = fopen("exampleWheel.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "can't open file");
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**In line 11, I want to replace the string "exampleWheel.txt" with the value of argv[ 1 ] so that I can open any .txt file.**

Please show me how I can apply this to my existing code.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: You don't think that `fopen(argv[1], ..` would work?

Comment: @usr2564301 it should, as the first element in argv will be the actual program invocation instruction.

Comment: @DanielLozano: OP proved that it does. Hence my bewilderment.

Comment: It gave me an error because I had char **argv[] instead of char *argv[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your initial problem is here:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv[])
{
```

`char **argv[]` is ***wrong***. It's either `char *argv[]` or `char **argv`

You have one too many levels of indirection for `argv`. See: [C11 Standard - §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup(p1)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). Your compiler should be screaming warnings at you...

You do have warnings enabled right? `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` for gcc/clang or `/W3` for VS. I suspect after you fix the invocation for `main` and make the replacement you want -- all will work correctly.

Since you are wanting to pass the filename as an argument to `main()` (which is the proper way to do it), you also need to ensure the user provide all required arguments before passing `argv[1]` to `fopen`. You can do this with a simple `if (argc < 2)` check to check you have at least 2 arguments provided to the program.

Incorporating the check, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fPointer;

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate required arguments provided */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: insufficient input.\n"
                         "usage: %s <filename>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    if ((fPointer = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fopen-argv[1]");       /* a fopen failure sets errno, use perror */
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note above that on failure the `fopen` function sets `errno` which allows you to output the system error using the `perror()` function. You can use that in addition to, or in lieu of your `fprintf` message. When you include `stdlib.h` you have the system macros defined for `EXIT_SUCCESS` (value is `0`) and `EXIT_FAILURE` (value is `1`), you can use instead of hardcoding `exit(1);`. Up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification :)

Answer (score 1):

In the `fopen` call, change `"exampleWheel.txt"` to `argv[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a functional example. You need to skip argv[0] as it contains the actual program invocation command.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    char filename[100], c;

    for (i=1; i < argc; i++){

        FILE *fPointer =  fopen(argv[i], "r");

        if (fPointer == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "can't open file");
            exit(1);
        }


        // Read contents from file
        c = fgetc(fPointer);
        while (c != EOF)
        {
            printf ("%c", c);
            c = fgetc(fPointer);
        }
        printf ("\n");

        fclose(fPointer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I hope it helps!